# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway but works with port

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I configured a NGINX server with the configuration below.

In a browser, if I type `sub.domain.com`, I end up on a `502 Bad Gateway` page.

If I type `sub.domain.com:8772`, it works, but I would to avoid having to enter the port.

If I force the IP address in the configuration as follows `proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8772;`, it displays the page but some parts are not well displayed (missing images, ...).

Do you know what I do wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name sub.domain.com;
  client_max_body_size 256m;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8772;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've same problem,nginx return 502, but 80 prot worked.
maybe you have to see the dns settings.